# html: get a banner to span greater than display width

Tags: html

This example is boiled down from a much (MUCH) larger page.
If you display the HTML you'll see a green bar than spans the display,
underneath which is content wider than the display.

What I need is for that upper bar to be as long as the lower content, so that
when the content is wider than the screen, and the user scrolls, that upper
bar continues all the way to the right edge. I can't find a way to do that.

Any ideas? Thanks much-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
.topborder
{
  background-color : #4F8816;
  height: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;"><div><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px" style="height: 100%;">
<tr><div style="width: max-content;" class="topborder"></div></tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 175px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: top;">
    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-left: 10px; border-left: #999999 1px solid;">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="2" id="ID0EGJEK">
            <tr>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
                <th >xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table></div></body>
</html>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3ngcv1z5/)

Comment: can you please post a fiddle too explaining your situation..

Answer (score 0):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/g572dhx9/)

The problem with your code was that, actually you had 12 `<td>`s for one of your `<tr>` and thus it got expanded.So, i've just added a `colspan` which is equal to 12 which made the width of all the `<tr>`s equal..

Check more about `colspan` attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

This is the html part that i've changed..

```
<tr>
     <td colspan="12">
          <div style="width: max-content;" class="topborder"></div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That did it, all right. Here's the problem with the solution ;-> The page is put together in stages by different pieces of software. The piece that puts out that green banner has no idea how many columns there are going to be. Can you think of a way to do this in the absence of that knowledge? Many thanks-

Comment: The problem is that the solution requires the use of the literal number "12", which is the number of columns in the subsequent content. When the top banner's html is generated, the number of columns is unknown-- it could be 5 or 30. It's not possible to specify at that point. I know that's silly in the context of the boiled-down example, but that was the price of making a small, simple example. I might be able to go back and alter the page after it's rendered, but a static way to make the html treat the whole page as being as wide as the widest content would be simpler. Thanks again-

Comment: using colspan="arbitrarily-huge-number" DOES work, at least in the example, but not in the real situation. I'll have to bottom that out. Thanks for getting me on the road.